# What is the expected value of the number of die rolls necessary to get a specific number?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Given a discrete random number generator, such as a six-sided die, what is the expected value of the number of rolls necessary to roll a specific number (e.g. a six)?

I think the result should be given by E$\langle$rolls$\rangle$ = $\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(\frac{5}{6})^n(n+1)}$, but I don't know how to calculate the convergence of that sum.

Also, how do I calculate the variance?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A slightly simpler recursive derivation is this. We must roll the die at least once. On the first roll we get a 6 with probability $\frac{1}{6}$. Otherwise we start again. Hence, $E = 1 + \frac{5}{6}E$, which gives $E=6$.

Here is a more general answer:

Regard rolling the die as a Bernoulli process $X_1,X_2, \ldots$, where $X_i = $ Success, with probability $p$, and $X_i = $ Failure, with probability $1-p$. The process stops after the first success.

Let $N_s$ be the length of the sequence until the first Success. This is a random integer. Then we have
$$
\Pr (N_s=k) = \Pr(\underbrace{FF\cdots F}_{k-1}\ S) =
\underbrace{(1-p)(1-p)\cdots(1-p)}_{k-1}\ p=(1-p)^{k-1}p=pq^{k-1},
$$
where $q=1-p$ and $k\ge1$. This is called a **Geometric Distribution**,
which is the discrete equivalent of the **Exponential Distribution**. Random variables with these distributions are called *memoryless*. (See Ross, *Introduction to Probability Models*, 9th Edition, page 284.)

The expected value and variance of $N_s \sim \text{Geom}(p)$ are
$$
\text{E}{N_s(p)}=\frac{1}{p}, \text{  and  } \text{Var}{N_s(p)} = \frac{1-p}{p^2}.
$$Proof can be found in Ross, above. Note that $$\text{E}{N_s(p)} = 1 +(1-p)\text{E}{N_s(p)}, \text{ whose solution is } \frac{1}{p}.$$

In your case $p = \frac{1}{6}\,$ and so E(No. rolls) = 6, and Var(No. rolls) = 30 -- Geom$(\frac{1}{6})$ has a long tail.

Answer (score 35):

One "trick" that often lets you avoid issues of convergence when solving probability problems is to use a recursive argument.

You have a 1/6 probability of rolling a 6 right away, and a 5/6 chance of rolling something else and starting the process over (but with one additional roll under your belt).

Let $E$ be the expected number of rolls before getting a 6; by the reasoning above, we have:

> $E = (1)(1/6) + (E + 1)(5/6)$

Solving for $E$ yields $E = 6$.

An alternative approach is to use the generating function.  The generating function $G(t)$ for a probability distribution that only takes on integer values is defined as:

> $G(t) = \Sigma_{i = 0}^{\infty} p_i t^i$

The reason the generating function comes in handy is that $G'(1)$ gives the expected value and $G''(1) + G'(1) - (G'(1))^2$ gives the variance; one can check this directly.

In our case, the generating function is:

> $G(t) = (1/6)t + (1/6)(5/6)t^2 + (1/6)(5/6)^2t^3 + \ldots$

We can rewrite this as follows:

> $G(t) = (1/5)(5t/6 + (5t/6)^2 + (5t/6)^3 + \ldots)$

Summing the geometric series gives $G(t) = t/(6-5t)$; from here, we can calculate $G'(t)$ and $G''(t)$, plug in $t = 1$, and use the above expressions to extract both the expected value and the variance (6 and 30, respectively).

Answer (score 9):

Elliott's answer is surely the nicest. To sum the series, we can use a method similar to the geometric series.

Let $$S = 1 + 2 \cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right) + 3 \cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2 + \cdots $$

Then

$$\frac{5}{6}S = \frac{5}{6} + 2 \cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2 + 3 \cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3 + \cdots $$

$$S - \frac{5}{6}S = 1+ \left(\frac{5}{6}\right) +\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2 + \cdots $$

This is just a geometric series and hence we have that

$$S = 36$$

Now we have that $$\frac{1}{6} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n (n+1) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot S = 6,$$ as expected.

(Convergence of the series can be seen by the ratio test)

Comment: Very nice. It's great to see so many different ways to find the convergence value for power series.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an intuitive argument. Roll the die $6000$ times. You'd expect there to be $1000$ 6's among them. Consider the gaps between successive 6's in the list (plus the initial gap to the first 6). These lengths are the values of independent draws from a geometric RV with $p=1/6$, so the average gap length is the expected value you want.

The sum of these (~1000) gap lengths is 6000, and so the average gap is $6000/1000=6$ (modulo a little fudge at the end which would go to $0$ by making the string longer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but here's a slightly different path to the same solution. Let $X$ be the number of die rolls until we roll a specific number. Let $p$ be the probability that we roll the specific number and $q = 1-p$ be the probability that we roll any of the other numbers. We know

$$
\mathbb{E}[X] \triangleq 1p + 2qp + 3q^2 p + 4q^3p + \dots
$$

Note that the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} q^x = \frac{q}{1-q}$. Using this fact and a little algebra and calculus, we get,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X]
&= 1p + 2qp + 3q^2 p + 4q^3p + \dots
\\
&= \sum_{x = 0}^{\infty} (x + 1) q^x p
\\
&= \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} x q^{x-1} p
\\
&= \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial q} q^x p
\\
&= p \frac{\partial}{\partial q} \Big( \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} q^x \Big)
\\
&= p \frac{\partial}{\partial q} \Big( \frac{q}{1-q} \Big)
\\
&= p \frac{1}{(1 - q)^2}
\\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{6}}{\big(1 - \frac{5}{6}\big)^2}
\\
&= 6
\end{align}
$$