# Rolling a die until obtain the face $1$, conditioned on all of the rolls landing face up on odd number?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice

Suppose you have a fair six-sided die. What is the expected value of rolls until a $1$ face up,  conditioned on all of the rolls landing face up on odd number?

If $A$ represents: rolling a die $n$ times, at $n$th time we get $1$ faced up, $(n-1)$th we have odd number faced up
$B$ represents: we get odd number for all $n$ times
$P(A|B) = \frac{[(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}(\frac{1}{6})]}{(\frac{1}{2})^n}.$

I think $P(A|B)$ represents the probability of rolling a die until obtain the face $1$, conditioned on all of the rolls landing face up on odd number.

I calculate the limit of $P(A|B)$ and get $\frac{1}{3}$;

Based on my undertstanding from this post: [What is the expected value of the number of die rolls necessary to get a specific number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42930/what-is-the-expected-value-of-the-number-of-die-rolls-necessary-to-get-a-specifi)
$E = 1 + \frac{2}{3} E$ then I guess the expected value is $3$? I am not sure about the answer. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hello @Squirrel K, welcome to MSE. Please add in your question (not in the comments) what attempt you have made and tell where exactly you got stuck. Questions without context or questions that have the appearance of homework, are not always well received on this site.

Comment: Just added my solution! First time using this website. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Just added my thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only numbers that matter are $1,3,5$, so we can discount any rolls in which these numbers do not arise.  Of course of the remaining, admissible, rolls, there is a $1/3$ chance each of these arises.

It is unclear whether the conditions admit a $1$ on the first roll as "acceptable" (since no prior rolls were of odd numbers).  Assuming an initial $1$ is *not* admissible, the only rolls that need be considered start with a $3$ or $5$.

Given that condition, there is a $1/3$ chance any particular odd number arises on a given roll.

So there is a $1/3$ chance the game ends with a $1$ on the second roll.

What is the chance that it ends on the third roll?  That arises only if a $3$ or $5$ appears on the second roll (chance = $2/3$) and a $1$ appears on the third roll $1/3$ or $2/9$.

Can you continue to the next roll?  Can you generalize from here?